# Setting autoComplete off is not working on Field from "redux-form"

Tags: reactjs

When I add `autoComplete= "off"` into Field component from "redux-form", chrome doesn't turn off the autocomplete,

```
            <FormGroup htmlFor="qualification">
          <Label htmlFor="qualification">{t("hoksobjective.qualification")}</Label>
          <Field
            t={t}
            id={"qualification"}
            name={"qualification"}
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder={t("hoksobjective.placeholders.qualification")}
            component={AutoComplete}
            suggestions={this.props.codes.qualification}
            format={value => (value && value.names ? value.names[lng].value : value)}
            onChange={onQualificationChange}
            custom={{
              onListItemClick: e => {
                handleChange("qualification", e);
              },
              renderOptionName: suggestion => suggestion.names[lng].value,
            }}
            disabled={!editPsapObjective}
          />
        </FormGroup>
```

but when I add `autoComplete = "off"` to its parent Form component from "redux-form", it's working. How can I turn off the autoCompolete from the Field component?

Comment: Have you solved this, came up to the same issue, but myself being on firefox, and autoComplete="off" on the <form> tag isn't working either.

Comment: @Danys Chalifour I hope this can help, if I remember correctly I did: 1. Go to chrom setting 2. Go to section 'Autofill' 3. Go to section 'address and more' 4. Disable 'save and fill addresses', please check detail from https://www.howtogeek.com/425270/how-to-disable-form-autofill-in-google-chrome/ Probably the same to firefox, please check from https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-Do-I-Disable-or-Clear-AutoFill-AutoComplete-Information-#h_01EFPN2ZYQD9HYK4VXVZ08JQ6R